# Re-requesting input from user when an exception occurs

Tags: java, exception

I am new in java. I have written a program in which the user chooses how many numbers he wants to add. If the user enters a string it will throw an exception and the programs tell the user to enter all details again.

My problem is i want the program to ask the user to re enter details from that number which he entered wrong.

Eg: the user chooses to add 4 numbers but he enters the third number as string, the program should ask the user to re-enter from the third number and not the entire details again.

```
My code is as follow:


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Add
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        boolean loop=true;
        while(loop)
        try
        {
            String yn;
            do
            {
                Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter how many numbers to add: ");
                int num=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
                int a,sum=0;
                for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter number["+i+"]: ");
                    a=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
                    sum=sum+a;
                }
                System.out.println("The Sum is:"+sum);
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue?(Y/N):");
                yn=s.next();

            } while(yn.equals("y")||yn.equals("Y"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Try Again\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your `try` and `catch` should be nested somewhere different.  Maybe inside your `for` loop, or maybe you'll need another loop.  It's always a good idea to try and figure out these things with pencil and paper before you write too much code.

Comment: Simply place the `try-catch` statements a loop deeper.

Comment: Use `scanner.nextInt()` instead of `scanner.next()` - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextint.htm

Comment: @Zhuinden, slightly better style but doesn't address the exception handling issue

Comment: Also, as a general principle, writing `catch(Exception e)` is often a bad idea.  Exceptions can be thrown for all sorts of reasons, and usually if you're handling an exception, you'll want to be precise about what sort of exception you're going to handle.  In this case, it would be better to write `catch(NumberFormatException e)` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this, by placing the "retry" one level deeper in the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Add {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        boolean loop=true;
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(loop) {
            try {
                String yn;
                do {
                    loop = true;
                    System.out.println("Enter how many numbers to add: ");
                    int num=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
                    int a,sum=0;
                    for(int i=1;i<=num;) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Enter number["+i+"]: ");
                            a=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
                            sum=sum+a;
                            i++;
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Invalid input. Try Again.\n");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("The Sum is:"+sum);
                    System.out.println("Do you want to continue?(Y/N):");
                    yn=s.next();
                    loop = yn.equals("y")||yn.equals("Y");
                } while(loop);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Number of elements invalid. Try Again.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As @Zhuinden indicates, one better uses `Scanner.nextInt`, since it is more generic...

Comment: Nope, that requests n numbers only, invalid and valid ones. It needs to add up n valid numbers.

Comment: It does, the increment `i++` is only executed at the end of the `try` block.

Comment: @Paul I believe you are mistaken.  This solution looks correct to me.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the horrible for-loop with missing step and separate i++

Comment: @Paul: I agree there are better ways to handle this. Using more dedicated frameworks ;)

Comment: @Paul I don't think so.  It prints a nice message and prompts the user again.  Is that called barfing?

Comment: Oh, foo. Not enough coffee. Sorry, deleting my comment

Comment: The only problem i m facing now is when i enter "N" for "do you want to continue?" it doesnt exit

Comment: @MohammedRampurawala: That was already part of the provided solution. `[Modified]` Does it work now?

Comment: @CommuSoft But now even when i type "Y" it exits

Comment: @MohammedRampurawala: sorry, made a typo. Works now?

Answer (score 1):

Below code should help

```
int i =1;
    while(i <=num){

        System.out.println("Enter number["+i+"]: ");
        try{
            a=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
            sum=sum+a;
            i++;
        }catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid interger");
        }




    }
```

Comment: That adds 'a' to sum even if the parse of the integer fails

Answer (score 0):

Use additional method that reads single entry until it is valid number:

```
private static int readNumber(Scanner s) {
    Integer value = null;

    while (value == null) {
        try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(s.next());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("bad format, try again...");
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Then you can use this method whenever you can read valid number:

```
System.out.println("Enter how many numbers to add: ");
int num = readNumber(s);
...

System.out.println("Enter number[" + i + "]: ");
a = readNumber(s);
....
```

Method getNumber(s) guarantee to return only when user give correct integer.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what happens if the user types a sentence consisting of several words, in place of a number.

Comment: does the line `int num = readNumber(s);` even work? I mean, you can't just give `null` as parameter to an `int`, can you? And the method itself should be returning `Integer`, and not `int`. Was this even tested?

Comment: this not only been tested, but also works. Method readNumber return  int, because this method returns only if s.next() is valid integer, so value is never null (while value==null prevents this). **Below sample session:** `>Enter how many numbers to add: 
>2
>Enter number[1]: 
>111
>Enter number[2]: 
>eee
>bad format, try again...
>fff
>bad format, try again...
>222
>The Sum is:333`

Comment: session with **several words** instead of valid integer:
`>Enter how many numbers to add: 
>1
>Enter number[1]: 
>one two three
>bad format, try again...
>bad format, try again...
>bad format, try again...
>5
>The Sum is:5`

Answer (score 0):

works according to what you want, but not ethical

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class Add
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        boolean loop=true;int pos=0;int num=0,sum=0;
        while(loop)
        try
        {
            String yn;
            do
            {sum=0;num=0;
                Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Enter how many numbers to add: ");
                 num=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
                int a;
                for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter number["+i+"]: ");
                    a=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
                    sum=sum+a;pos=i;
                }
                System.out.println("The Sum is:"+sum);
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue?(Y/N):");
                yn=s.next();

            } while(yn.equals("y")||yn.equals("Y"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { 

            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            int a=0;
            for(int i=pos+1;i<=num;i++)
            { System.out.println("Enter number["+i+"]: ");
            a=Integer.parseInt(s.next());
            sum=sum+a;}
            System.out.println("The Sum is:"+sum);
        }
    }
}
```